# Use of back ticks vs quotes

Tags: discussion, formatting

I just answered a question and as per being beaten into submission multiple times in the past by people editing my previous missives, I used back ticks to highlight some text. (See [my answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/126277/6188))

But what was interesting is that someone replied with the comment

> It's not enough of a change for me to put an edit through, but code
>   blocks are not for emphasis, and using them as such is detrimental to
>   the Stack Exchange experience, especially for users of assistive
>   technologies like screen readers. The backticks (`) should be replaced
>   with single (') or double (") quotes

I had never considered this before.  So what is the consensus on back ticks?  What should I be using?

Comment: It's sad when somebody who is right gets beaten into submission by people who are wrong. So thanks for asking to clear this up!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Backticks create `<code>` blocks, which have a specific purpose in markup that is utilized on the technical stacks where actual computer code must be indicated, but [less so on non-technical stacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254393) such as this one. They should be used for [code and code-like artifacts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112) and [not for highlighting](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7437).

It [dirties the semantics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112) of the network to use this markup in the interest of providing highlighted monospace text, which isn't even a standard way of formatting English. It [makes the site unusable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755) to people using assistive technologies. [Besides, it's ugly](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4722/16052).

You shouldn't use them for presentation. The markup here allows for boldface, italics, and blockquotes, size adjustments, and of course capitalization and punctuation. I like a clean, searchable site, as I think most do, so I use boldface for emphasis and italics for terminology or use-mention distinctions, and headlines where a long answer is benefited by headlines, and that has been entirely adequate.

Comment: It maybe that I came into all of this via stack overflow, so in going back there just now and looking at a random question I see multiple people using backticks to identify and emphasize non-code items inline.  But now I consider myself educated on the matter and will refrain from using them in the future.  I really had no idea that there rendered as code blocks

Comment: Does it really mess up screen readers? Is there an example proving this?

Comment: Does the average travel user know or care about all this?

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen no, but a travel user using an assistive technology might.

Comment: @JonathanReez: It *might*.  Good screen readers encountering a `<code>` block need to ensure that the user is given a completely unambiguous readout of every character (so that if you write something like `&((*foo)->bar[7])`, blind users can properly appreciate its monstrosity).  A screen reader could choose to spell out one letter at a time instead of reading whole words, but there's no formal spec requiring it to do so.  However, it does need to distinguish between `foobar`, `FooBar`, `Foobar`, `fooBar`, and `foo_bar`, so spelling out may be safer in the presence of mixed case.

Comment: @Kevin again, that's just a conjecture. Have there been any actual complaints from persons with less than perfect sight about people using code blocks?

Comment: @JonathanReez: Yes, there have been such complaints.  See the notice across the top of the "makes the site unusable" link.